# Laravel: how to organize BaseContoller

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-4

I'm going to have a method in my `BaseController` to detect the city that user is from.
What is the best way to do that? I also want to make use of Automatic Resolution and pass to `BaseController`'s constuctor some kind of `LocationService`.

```
<?php
use Andrew\Services\LocationService;

class BaseController extends Controller {

protected $locationService;

public function __construct( LocationService $locationService )
{
    $this->locationService = $locationService;
    $this->detectLocation();
}

/**
 * Setup the layout used by the controller.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function setupLayout()
{
    if ( ! is_null($this->layout))
    {
        $this->layout = View::make($this->layout);
    }
}

public function detectLocation()
{
    $this->locationService->detect();
}
```

}

If I take this approach then I'll have to pass an instance of `LocationService` from every sub-controller to parent's cunstructor

```
// Sub-controller

public function __construct( CalculatorValidator $validator, TotalCostService $totalCost)
{
    parent::__construct(new LocationService);
    $this->validator = $validator;
    $this->totalCost = $totalCost;
}
```

Is it appropriate way to accomplish what I need? Doesn't it seems like a lot of work?

Comment: Are you sure you want to inject that? Seems it would be more clean to have a `LocationService` facade (as in Laravel) that would be resolved via `App::make()` even that it couples your classes. Anyway, where do you need the result of `$this->locationService->detect()` ?

Comment: @SergeyTelshevsky yes, facade is an option too. I'm going to need the result of `$this->locationService->detect()` in each controller or actually in my layout view - once I've detected the user's location I show them their city.
Could you explain why facade is better option?

Comment: Well, it's mostly a matter of preference, but I don't think having to inject something in a controller that is used only in *some*, even if it's not *some*, but *many* methods (think of post actions and json responses that don't need it) is a good approach. You may simply do it in your `detectLocation` method by instantiating the service and detecting as you do it. Simply think about a situation if there will be many more similar things you'll need to show. A constructor will be filled with things not used so often.

Comment: Couldnt you put "detect location" in the App::before() filter or something? Then run it there once - rather than in your controller? I dont think the controller is the right place for it...

Comment: If you just need to get the data into a view each time, just use a view composer, and your best bet would be to put that into your `LocationService` service provider.  It would probably be the cleanest method and require the least amount of work.